# What is the correct way to store and then display DateTimes in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I think I may have been living in a cave for some time as the complexities of `DateTime` has only sunk in today.  I've read a few articles that recommend always storing `DateTime` as `UTC` in the database and then display them as a local time in a view.

However, I then hit the articles that said its not that simple and you need to consider "instants" and converting the user inputted `DateTime` to `UTC` is hard due to the `TimeZone Id` or using `ToUniversalTime()` is not safe or you could let `JavaScript` post a `UTC DateTime` and use `JS` to display local times but what if I have a `Razor` view with a `DateTime` model property?  Even relying on `ToLocalTime()` cannot be considered safe apparently.

I've heard of Noda Time from Jon Skeet which I'm hoping solves all this although I know he has commented that its not perfect.

So what in the hell are people using even for very simple web applications in `.Net`?

Is there a correct example that you could provide or link to which posts and then renders the value which is timezone sympathetic?

It appears ignorance is bliss.

**UPDATE:** For example, a user has a DateTimePicker from jQuery and they select a datetime of an event.  Users of the application are global so if they choose 10am Eastern US time it should appear in the view as 6pm for UK users.

Comment: Perhaps if you told us a little more about your specific use case, we could be clearer about how to handle your specific situation properly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I think that's the key. Regardless of the problem you're trying to solve, don't solve what's not on the radar, just solve your use case. It's impossible to solve the unknown unknowns.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Added an update

Comment: [Globalization is a fairly well-worn path.](https://www.google.com/search?q=globalizing+dates+in+an+asp.net+mvc+application)

Comment: Its well worn but even this simple example there is no definitive answer just more debate and redirection

Comment: @Jon, what ***exactly*** do you mean by `no definitive answer just more debate and redirection`? Have you been through the first result by Scott?

Comment: I don't think so.  Globalization is a fairly standard thing to do to a website, and the books and blogs describe it in a fairly straightfoward fashion; you just have to learn it.

Comment: Are you not getting local time in a DateTimePicker?

Comment: @Blam I believe this uses local time http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ so now what?

Comment: My understanding is you wanted local time.  SO is for specific programming questions.  Post the problem code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look on all technologies we have:
SQL Server (I consider that you use SQL Server, because of MS Stack) - the [DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) type does not store Time zone offset range, so this does not give us other options than just keep them in UTC.

.NET gives you an option to manipulate with Time Zones in DateTime type. So you can load values from database and change it somehow to user timezone. And this is good question, how to determinate what is the user timezone? Ok, so if user registered on the size - you can just use settings like 'Your timezone' and store it for all users (a branch of sites do this, like Sharepoint), so each time you render View - you use this setting and render view with right timezone. The problem with this can be that if you will need to use caching - you will need to cache based on the user time zones (not the best, huh)...

But what if you have some user which is anonymous and you don't have information on him?

Let's take a look on JavaScript. JavaScript allows you to manipulate with time zones. You can render all date related strings on server as `<date>2013-04-08T12:00:00Z</date>`, which indicates that date in UTC, after this `onload` you can launch JS code which will find all `date` tags on view and transform them to browser Time Zone. (I have an article about this problem [Developing web application with time zones support](http://outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/198), it has a lot of grammar mistakes, sorry for that).

So, for me - the right way to do this is to keep everything in UTC untill you will not show it to user. Only View should manipulate with dates in User Time Zone (in your case this should be only JavaScript layer), every time you need to send data with dates to server - you need to convert this dates to UTC. Each time you get dates from server - convert them first to browser time zone and after this show it to user.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how I do it. .NET has a property called [Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx). What I do is I have a string field in my database called UserTimeZome and somewhere in the user settings, the user can set his or her time zone. You can enumerate a drop down list using [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397781.aspx).

Once the user has picked his or her time zone, I store the [DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.displayname.aspx) in the UserTimeZone field in my database. Now I have the ability to convert UTC time to their local time zone and visa versa. I can use the [ConvertTimeToUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915.aspx) method or the [ConvertTimeFromUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx) method. Be sure to update the Kind Property by creating a new DateTime and setting the Kind on the DateTime constructor.

Together with that, I can convert any date/time to local time or UTC time. Now if you need to do this from javascript, rather then from C#, I use [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/). MomentJs can convert to and from UTC and local time using the [UTC functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

I hope this helps you out